# TeXShop find panel disappears after hit

Tags: texshop

With a successful match with the find panel of TeXShop you end up back in the main document with the cursor at the match (highlighted). This behaviour is weird, is there any way to avoid this and stay in the find panel? The reason is of course that I want to continue pressing Enter for the next match (the first match might not be the one I'm interested in). To do this now I need to press Alt-f in between each Find.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. There is often a separate shortcut for jumping to the next result, in TeXworks and Opera for example this is Ctrl + G. Is there a similar one in TeXShop? I guess it will be listed under Edit --> Find if that is the case.

Answer (score 2):

This is 'by design' and as observed in comments not unique to TeXshop. You can bring up the Find box with Cmd-F then search for the first hit. To find the next hit it's Cmd-G.